# WPF Button.Content binding how to use RelativeSource from parent window in usercontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

In a WPF application with MVVM pattern I have a button.Contenet in binding with a propety in the mainwindow:

```
 <Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding Stamp, Mode=TwoWay }"/>
```

I'm trying to figure out how the binding relativesource works.I need to take the "Stamp" content in a UserControl

```
 <Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding DataContext.MainWindowViewModel.Stamp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor , AncestorType={x:Type Button }}}"/>
```

But it does not work.

The full XAML code of MainWindow is:

```
<Window x:Class=" WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4.WpfApplication4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:uc1VM}">
        <local:UserControl1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:uc2VM}">
        <local:UserControl2/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txbFieldDescription" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinWidth=" 90" Text="{Binding FieldDescription, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height=" 22">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"  CommandParameter="{x:Type local:uc1VM}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"  CommandParameter="{x:Type local:uc2VM}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>


        <Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding Stamp, Mode=TwoWay }"/>

    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding UCVM}"  />
</Grid>
```

This is also the code of the MainViewModel:

```
Namespace WpfApplication4

Public Class MainWindowViewModel
    ' Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Private m_ucVM As Object
    Public Property UCVM() As Object
        Get
            Return m_ucVM
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            m_ucVM = value
            OnPropertyChanged("UCVM")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private mStamp As String
    Public Property Stamp() As String
        Get
            Return mStamp
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mStamp = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Stamp")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _navigateCommand As RelayCommand(Of Type)
    Public ReadOnly Property NavigateCommand() As RelayCommand(Of Type)
        Get
            If _navigateCommand IsNot Nothing Then
                Return _navigateCommand
            Else
                Return New RelayCommand(Of Type)(Sub(newVMType)
                                                     UCVM = Nothing
                                                     If newVMType.Name = "uc1VM" Then
                                                         Stamp = "Ciao vecchio"
                                                     Else
                                                         Stamp = "Ciao nuovo"
                                                     End If
                                                     UCVM = Activator.CreateInstance(newVMType)
                                                 End Sub)
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        Stamp = "Ciao Primo"
    End Sub

End Class
```

End Namespace

The UsersControls XAML is the same for Both :

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid >
    <Button x:Name="button" Height=" 20" Width=" 120" Content="{Binding DataContext.Stamp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent  }}"/>
</Grid>
```

I simplified it all to better understand.
I uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8vxXZ11kiMWVW1CRERJSl9QVFU) a sample project.

Comment: Where exactly is the `Stamp` property and where is your `Button`located (in the main window of part of an `ItemTemplate` of a collection)?

Comment: It's based on MVVM pattern, so the Stam property is in the VM of the MainWindow. There are two buttons, one in the main window and the other in the usercontrol. I need to take the content from button on main window and put it in the content of the user control.

Comment: I guess you are using the `UserControl` in your `Window`. Have you tried setting the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` with the one of the `Window` and binding the `Content` of the `Button` like you did it in the `Window`?

Comment: Both View and Usercontrol have the datacontext set to their VM (MainViewVM and UserControlVM).

Comment: And have you tried it in the `UserControl` without the `RelativeSource`?

Comment: Somethink like this in my usercontrol?   <Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding DataContext.Stamp}"/> Yes, but dosn't work.

Comment: Without the Datacontext. Try the same like you did in your `Window`.

Comment: The Stamp property is setted on VM of the MainWindow. The Usercontrol without the right path dosn't know where take vale.

Comment: Where do you use the `UserControl`? Can't find it in your xaml.

Comment: <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:uc1VM}">
        <local:UserControl1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:uc2VM}">
        <local:UserControl2/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the AncestorType is set to `x:Type Button`. You should search for thetype of your parent-View instead, because you want to bind to the datacontext (viewmodel) of this type.

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding DataContext.Stamp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor , AncestorType={x:Type VIEW}}}"/>
```

**EDIT:**

I downloaded your sample project and updated the UserControl1.xaml to this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid >
        <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Height=" 22" Content="{Binding DataContext.Stamp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow }}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With this edit, the button of the usercontrol shows the correct content.

Comment: Can you provide the xaml code of your mainView where the usercontrol is set?

Comment: In this case the UserControl is stored in the DataTemplate? So probably you could try it with {Binding DataContext.Stamp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}

Comment: I define two datatemplate. Then I load onetime Usercontrol1 and onetime UserControl2. There is only one button in the usercontrol. I need to take the Stamp value and set to the usercontrol button.Content

Comment: And the button you want to bind to Stamp value is located in UserControl1 or 2? I think we need some more clarification here

Comment: The Usercontrols have the same button and the same XAML. I need only to take a value from the MainWindowVM and pass it to the Usercontrols.

Comment: What do you mean? When I load the main window, there are no user controls displayed. They are related to GotFocus and LostFocus events in the TextBox.Each time I create a new instance of controls when event occurs.

Comment: @GianfrancoVrech And you tried it with Eikes solution with `AncestorType={x:Type Window}`?

Comment: Of course. I tried both ( window and template). But no luck.

Comment: I edited my answer regarding your sample project. The solution was to change the ancestortype to the mainwindow type. Full changes to your sample in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding DataContext.Stamp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

It binds to the `Stamp` property of the `DataContext` of the parent window.

Comment: I've shared a solution. You can view as well.

Comment: Yes and it dosn't work. I have edited my original question and I've shared a project for download.